# How to make a push script from bash?

Tags: shell, github

I have many repositories on github.
I want to automatization push process to github.

Now i using script in package.json

```
"script":{
"git push all": "npm run all repo1 repo2 repo3 ... etc"
}
```

It works, but it is very difficult to changes when i add or remove repositories.

How can i create script for push in sh script ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems a tool capable of handling multiple repositories at once would fit the bill; once such tool is [myrepos](http://myrepos.branchable.com/). Register each repository you want to track with `mr register`; then you’ll be able to push, pull etc. all your tracked repositories at once.